# Standard method for validating a group of XML files against schemas and each other

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, relationship

I'm developing a data transfer standard which is going to involve (simplistically) a client defining a project definition, in XML, to a project definition schema and a supplier supplying data which meets a data supply schema and the client defined project definition.

I know I can do this by convention/by defining a process to be followed, my question is "Is there an accepted standard way to do this type of thing?", perhaps using annotation/appinfo? (I've googled around and have come up empty)

An example of what I'm on about is below (most stuff stripped out for brevity):

Simplified Client Project Definition Schema

```
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="ProjectConfiguration">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Enum" type="EnumType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="EnumType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Client Project Definition XML

```
<ProjectConfiguration id="myproj">
    <Enum name="myenum">
        <Value>AllowedValue1</Value>
        <Value>AllowedValue2</Value>
    </Enum>
</ProjectConfiguration>
```

Simplified Supplier Data Supply Schema

```
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="Data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>
                        Here, I want the type to be validated against the list supplied
                        in the Client Project Definition XML.  I know (think) that XSD 
                        won't cut this, but am wondering if there is anything
                        that will in a standard manner. 
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

For the avoidance of doubt, I've got complete control over my codebase and no externally imposed constraints.  I do not want the client to be defining a schema for every project, as the eventual solution will involve multiple tiers/stock configurations (and inheritance and amendment of these via configuration).

If there is another way which is radically different to what I'm trying to do, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that the enumerations cannot be specified in a separate XML file and applied as constraints to values in an XSD.

> I do not want the client to be defining a schema for every project, as
>   the eventual solution will involve multiple tiers/stock configurations
>   (and inheritance and amendment of these via configuration).

That's a bit vague as far as requirements go, but here are some other validation options if you're finding XSD 1.0 to be too limited:

- XSD 1.1 has assertions, although they're restricted to accessing the
  current node and its descendants.
- Schematron has assertions that are XPath based and can call user-defined
  functions (XSLT syntax), which in turn could consult other XML documents
  containing enumeration declarations, for example.
- Raw XSLT would provide the most power and flexibility, albeit at the
  expense of the standardization and predefined structure provided by
  Schematron.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers; it sounds like the Schematron method may be the best; standard and well understood - I'll investigate and, if it pans out, post an answer with the solution that worked in my instance.